# Recibir un context generico como parametro en una funcion. C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Estoy construyendo una api que maneja varias dbs, las cuales tienen los mismos formatos de tablas, pero cada db tiene diferentes datos. He creado los context con entity framework y uso un controlador para consultar a cada db, el codigo inicial seria este:

```
//inyeccion de las dbs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<RetailContext>(option =>
{
    option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RetailContext"));
});
builder.Services.AddDbContext<RetailCOContext>(option =>
{
    option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RetailCoContext"));
});

//inyeccion de dependencias
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICompradoresServices>(new CompradoresServices());

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/arg", (RetailContext db) =>
{
    IQueryable<CompradoresPersonas> compradores =
        from el in db.RetailHogarCompradoresPersonas
        select new CompradoresPersonas
        {
            IdEmpresa = el.Idempresa,
            IdPersona = el.Idpersona,
            UserId = el.UserId,

        };

    return compradores;
});

app.MapGet("/col", (RetailCOContext db) =>
{
    IQueryable<CompradoresPersonas> compradores =
        from el in db.RetailHogarCompradoresPersonas
        select new CompradoresPersonas
        {
            IdEmpresa = el.Idempresa,
            IdPersona = el.Idpersona,
            UserId = el.UserId,

        };

    return compradores;
});
```

Como se ve, estoy haciendo la misma consulta en los 2 controllers, solo que cambia el context, por lo que quise abstraer la consulta a un metodo aparte y lo hice de la siguiente manera:
Una interfaz:

```
 public interface ICompradoresServices
    {
        public CompradoresPersonas GetCompradores(QUE DEBERIA RECIBIR AQUI);
    }
```

y el servicio, que por supuesto no esta implementado aun ya que noy con los parametros:

```
public class CompradoresServices : ICompradoresServices
    {
        public CompradoresPersonas GetCompradores(QUE DEBERIA RECIBIR AQUI)
        {
            return new CompradoresPersonas();
        }
    }
```

El quedaria asi:

```
app.MapGet("/arg", (RetailContext db, CompradoresServices service) =>
{
    var compradores = service.GetCompradores(db.RetailHogarCompradoresPersonas);

    return compradores;
});

No doy con como recibir el parametro, si como DbContex xx, o como DbSet<xx>
```

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, a mí me parece que tendrías que enviar el Dbset.

No obstante, yo lo haría de esta manera

1. Creo un DbContext con toda la lógica, las tablas y todo lo que tiene un DbContext. El único punto extra es que debes crear un constructor de esta manera:
   (Le llamaremos RContext)

```
 public class RContext : DbContext
    {
        public RContext(DbContextOptions options): base(options)
        {
        }
 
       //Los DbSet aca
       // OnModelCreating y esas cosas si es que las ocupas 
      
    }
```

2. Luego creamos 2 (o más clases) según la cantidad de bases de datos que tengas. Las cuales extenderán de RContext. Estas clases no tendrán lógica

```
public class RetailContext: RContext
{
    public RetailContext() { }
    public RetailContext(DbContextOptions<RetailContext> options): base(options)
    {
    }
}

public class RetailCOContext: RContext
{
    public RetailCOContext() { }
    public RetailCOContext(DbContextOptions<RetailCOContext> options): base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

3. Creas una función statica en algún lado, a mi gusta en la misma clase CompradoresPersonas

```
public class CompradoresPersonas
{
  public int IdEmpresa {get;set;}
  public int IdPersona {get;set;}
  public int UserId {get;set;}

  public static IQueryable<CompradoresPersonas> GetCompradoresPersonas(RContext db)
  {
      return from el in db.RetailHogarCompradoresPersonas
        select new CompradoresPersonas
        {
            IdEmpresa = el.Idempresa,
            IdPersona = el.Idpersona,
            UserId = el.UserId,

        };
  }
}
```

4. Por último, tus controladores

```
app.MapGet("/arg", (RetailContext db) =>
{
    return CompradoresPersonas.GetCompradoresPersonas(db);
});

app.MapGet("/col", (RetailCOContext db) =>
{
    return CompradoresPersonas.GetCompradoresPersonas(db);
});
```

Esto se podría simplificar aún más si usamos la ruta para determinar a qué base de datos se debe llamar, y así se crea un solo controller. Pero creo que escapa de la pregunta original

Comment: Muchas gracias!! lo probare!!